# CLRS exercise 3.2-4 Big-Oh vs Little Oh

Tags: math, big-o, logarithm, clrs, little-o

I'm self studying CLRS, and I've hit this point - the question I'm answering is:

```
Is the function ⌈lglgn⌉! polynomially bounded?
```

And I've reduced it down to

```
=Θ(lglgn⋅lglglgn)
```

Now, all the solutions manuals seem to use little oh at this point to get it down to

`=o(lglgn⋅lglgn)`

And this step confounds me a little; I thought I understood little-oh, but clearly not well enough - can somebody frame it within this particular context? Also the next steps go from

```
=o(lg^2 n)
```

to

```
=o(lgn)
```

is this merely an application of L'hopitals rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a function that is asymptotically equivalent to `lglgn⋅lglglgn` (so it is in `Θ(lglgn⋅lglglgn)`), then `lglgn⋅lglgn` is an upper bound since `lglglgn` is in `o(lglgn)`.

I'm not sure about the last step:

- If `o(lg^2 n)` means `o((lg n)^2)`, you cannot say it is in `o(lg n)`. This is just wrong.
- If `o(lg^2 n)` means `o(lglg n)`, this is just switching to a larger upper bound due to `lglg n` is in `o(ln n)`.

Comment: Cheers mate, yeah it's the latter for the last step.